# How do I return to the screen in certain situations? (react-native)

Tags: react-native

There are A (from) -> B -> C -> D (to) screens.

I want to navigate to B from D in a specific situation.

I tried to send navigation parameters B to C to D and submit action occurred from D, navigate to B using the navigation parameters.

I think that is not the best way.

Is there any better way to navigate backward?

Comment: We can use navigation.navigate to go backward also it will cleared from stack

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators : you can refer to this for custom navigation

for more reference follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607156/react-native-go-back-to-a-specific-screen-in-stack

Comment: I know how to navigate. But, I wanna know go back to specific screen in specific situation.
For example, If I have a route parameter which includes information where to go in screen D, navigate to that route. This is what I did. But I wanna know better way not using route parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('B')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

you can just use:

```
navigation.navigate('B')
```

Then the navigation will back to B for you, or you can use this code:

```
navigation.pop()
navigation.pop()
```